# Is there a way to set an absolute URI or BaseAddress for HttpClient in Azure Functions Timer Trigger to reference internal servers?

Tags: function

Good day,
I am not a developer and thus need a really smart person to help me please.
Im trying to write an Azure Function Timer Trigger which needs to do availability checks on internal servers only. My last piece is the code to get the Function to reference internal servers by some means eg ip addy / url.
I have been given this code:
`{ // TODO: Replace with your business logic  //await httpClient.GetStringAsync(server_url); await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(server_url); }`

and this local.settings.json:
"SERVER_URL": "http://10.0.1.5/"

and im getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEEsp.png)

can any smart person advise me on how to either use the correct code above to reference ip addys / internal server urls? or how to add an absolute URI or BaseAddress.
Im stumped.
Thanks

I am not a developer so i did not edit any code. I did however try any format that was curl compliant - and still to no avail.